# Error: Cannot resolve entry file: The `main` field defined in your `package.json` points to a non-existent path

Tags: package.json, program-entry-point

I am getting this error: Error: Cannot resolve entry file: The `main` field defined in your `package.json` points to a non-existent path.
After upgrading expo 6.0.1

Comment: Issue occured after running the following command: npx expo install expo-asset@~8.6.2 expo-linking@~3.2.3

Comment: Getting the same problem, did you find a solution to this?